# Prime $\frak p\subset q\implies\exists$ prime $\frak p_1,q_1:p\subseteq p_1\subset q_1\subseteq q$ with no prime ideals between $\frak p_1,q_1$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This statement is Exercise 1.6 in this [book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Foundations_of_Commutative_Rings_and_The/13bbDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA64&printsec=frontcover) as well as Exercise 3 in this [note](https://math.mit.edu/%7Efgotti/docs/Courses/Ideal%20Theory/2.%20Prime%20and%20Maximal%20Ideals/Prime%20and%20Maximal%20Ideals.pdf):

> **Statement.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$. If $\mathfrak{p}\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}$, then there are prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1$ and $\mathfrak{q}_1$ in $R$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_1\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}_1\subseteq\mathfrak{q}$ and there are no other prime ideals between $\mathfrak{p}_1$ and $\mathfrak{q}_1$.

Here are my attempts. Consider the quotient ring $R/\mathfrak{p}$, which is an integral domain now.

Besides, we have $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}=\langle 0\rangle$ and $\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{p}\ne\langle 0\rangle$, both of which are prime ideals in $R/\mathfrak{p}$ as well.

Then how can we find such prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1$ and $\mathfrak{q}_1$? I was thinking of minimal prime ideals over $\mathfrak{p}$, but since $\mathfrak{p}$ itself is prime, it make no sense to consider it now. Any help will be appreciated.

---

**Update.** The proof of this result should be as follows: Consider the set $$S=\{(\mathfrak{p}',\mathfrak{q}')\in\operatorname{Spec}(R)\times\operatorname{Spec}(R)\mid\mathfrak{p}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}'\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}'\subseteq\mathfrak{q}\},$$ which is certainly nonempty as $(\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q})$ is contained in it. Next, define a partial order on $S$ by $$(\mathfrak{p}_1,\mathfrak{q}_1)\le(\mathfrak{p}_2,\mathfrak{q}_2)\iff\mathfrak{p}_1\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_2~\text{and}~\mathfrak{q}_2\subseteq\mathfrak{q}_1.$$ One can easily verify that $\le$ defines a partial order on $S$. Consider an ascending chain $(\mathfrak{p}_i,\mathfrak{q}_i)_{i\in\Gamma}$ in $S$. Define $$\mathfrak{p}_0:=\bigcup_{i\in\Gamma}{\mathfrak{p}_i}\quad\text{and}\quad\mathfrak{q}_0:=\bigcap_{i\in\Gamma}{\mathfrak{q}_i}.$$ Again, both $\mathfrak{p}_0$ and $\mathfrak{q}_0$ are clearly prime ideals in $R$, but there is a question:

> **Question.** Is $\mathfrak{p}_0\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}_0$?

If it is, then $(\mathfrak{p}_0,\mathfrak{q}_0)\in S$ as well. Finally, we simply let $(\mathfrak{p}_1,\mathfrak{q}_1)$ be the maximal element in $S$ ensured by Zorn's lemma.

I initially did not pay much attention to such question, but thought it would hold automatically. However, after rethinking it for a long time, I still do not get that. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any element $x\in \mathfrak{q} \setminus \mathfrak{p}$. Choose a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_0$ maximal among those which contain $\mathfrak{p}$, are contained in $\mathfrak{q}$ and do not contain $x$. Symmetrically, choose $\mathfrak{q}_0$ minimal among those primes which contain $\mathfrak{p}_0 + xR$ and are contained in $\mathfrak{q}$. Then, any prime between $\mathfrak{p}_0$ and $\mathfrak{q}_0$ would be equal to one of these, depending on whether it contains $x$ or not.